# return an empty vector c++

Tags: c++, object, vector, return

The requirement is that I need to search a vector to see if it contains the value passed in as the parameter. If the value exists in the vector, I return the vector. Else, I return an empty vector. I am not sure how to return an empty vector in c++. hope you could help me.
my mimic.h:

```
vector<Pair> map;
```

my Pair.h:

```
    Pair(){
}
~Pair(){}
string prefix;
vector<string> sufix;
```

Return vector function :

```
vector<string> Mimic::getSuffixList(string prefix){  
  int find=0;
  for(int i =0; i < map.size(); i++)
  {
   if(map[i].prefix == prefix)
   {

        find =1;
        return map[i].sufix; //sufix is a vector from a class called "Pair.h"
    }

   }
   if(find==0)
   {
         //return an empty vector. 
   }

  }
```

Comment: `{}` works well.

Comment: how to return an empty vector if the return type of the function is vector<T>& ?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Just

```
return vector<string>();
```

Or use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11)

```
return {};
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 1st solution be preferred since the intent of the programmer is clear? The 2nd one does not look so obvious to me.

Comment: I'm curious to know why we need () this, in the first solution...can't we just write the same without the brackets?

Comment: @codosopher `vector<string>` is just a type name, we need the `()` as `vector<string>()` to construct an object of type `vector<string>`.

Comment: I thought, to construct an object, we needed a new keyword. So, whenever I see a new keyword, I just assume that some object is created in a heap. But you said that we need () brackets to construct an object. So, am I wrong so far?

Comment: @codosopher Not only `new` can constructr object. For example you can check the syntax of [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).